# How to make a div popup on a certain screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm trying to build a div popup so when a users screen is below a certian (number px) it popups up saying this is recommended for a PC or tablet please help. I'm good at html, css, but i'm not good at JS/JavaScript.

Here is my DIV:

```
<div class="alert">
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    Recommended to be used on PC or tablet.
</div>
```

Here is my CSS for the DIV:

```
.alert {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f44336; /* Red */
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.closebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 13px;
}
.closebtn:hover {
  color: darkred;
}
```

Please don't dislike this page, But other than that please help me I'm very bad at JavaScript.
I tried looking up so many solutions but found none, but I know there is a solution and I'm expecting a code that gets the job done note again that I want a div not to show unless the screen size is below a certian px number. Thank you.

Comment: This is a job for a media query.  There's no Javascript needed at all.  Set up your media query for whatever `min-width` you desire and set the "alert" div to `display: none`.  This will ensure that the alert shows by default but doesn't display above the your preferred width.

Comment: I've added an example below. Hope this helps. Any questions drop me a comment and I'll sort.

Comment: nvm figured it out

Comment: Mega. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straightforward using media queries. Some info on [w3Schools here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

```css
.alert {
  display: none; /* at >600px width, don't display this */
  
  /* set the css up below so when we do display it, it appears correctly */
  position: fixed; /* position this fixed to the viewport */
  inset: 0; /* and make it expand to the top, bottom, left and right edges */
  background-color: rgba(255,255, 255, 0.9); /* apply a background to it to fade the contents out a bit using an opacity of 0.9 */

}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* apply this when the screen is less than or equal to 600 px wide */
  .alert {
    display: grid; /* use grid ... */
    place-items: center; /* .. to put the message in the center of the screen */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <div class='alert-message'> <!-- added this to contain the message details so they appear together -->
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    Recommended to be used on PC or tablet.
  </div>
</div>
<main>
  <h1>This is a title</h1>
  <p>This is some text</p>
</main>
```